# MySQL: Strings with Umlauts becomes Hexadecimal

Tags: php, mysql, sql, diacritics

I have seen some problems with the charset and umlauts (ä,ö,ü) but I have never seen something like this. So I hope someone can help.

Here is what I am trying to do. I send some customer data from a JavaScript file to a PHP file and then save them in a MySQL DB.

Therefore I generate a form in JS and `submit()` it with method POST (accept-charset="UTF-8" is set).
When watching the PHP file the SQL Query is displayed with the umlauts as it should be. 
BUT when I save it in the DB every String with umlauts becomes some hexadecimal value.

Here is the SQL Query

```
INSERT INTO anmeldungen 
    (uuid, name, email, address, zip, city, phone, nation, birth, uni, mnr, recommended, week0, week1, week2, week3, totalPrice, courseTotal, earlyBonus, priceToPay, toPayLater) 
VALUES
    ( "51ad3b36-8ff7-11e3-8299-406186eee454","Daniel Gördes","some@mail.com","Address 7","1010","Wien","123456789","deutsch","1989-05-07","Uni Wien","0001522633","Jhon Doe","Experimentelle Architektur","Karriere des Künstlers","","", "750","800","200","750","0" );
```

In the Database the name (Daniel Gördes) becomes `44616e69656c2047c3b672646573` this is the same with every string that contains umlauts. It is not always the same hexadecimal value.

The settings for the name field in the DB are `varchar(100)` and `collation utf8_bin`

I also use `$db->set_charset("utf8");` before sending the Query

Comment: Why do you use binary collation?

Comment: What database engine are you using? mysqli? pdo? mysql?

Comment: It becomes hexadecimal in the database? How exactly are you verifying that? Because it honestly looks like a mere setting in whatever GUI tool you are using to inspect data: in MySQL, `0x44616e69656c2047c3b672646573` is the same as to `'Daniel Gördes'`

Comment: Damn! I was looking for everything in my code but overlooked the collation of the DB.

As Thorsten mentioned the Problem was the collation `utf8_bin`. Just set it to `uft8_general_ci` and it works.

Comment: The problem with binary collation will be evident when you need to search or sort stuff but it shouldn't affect data storage at all. Displaying it as hex is the typical thing that PhpMyAdmin loves doing.